# Not able to dial number from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to give a choice to user for selecting a number for dialing. In my case I have textview which contains some phone numbers and I collected those numbers in array. Now when user clicked on a textview I want to display alerdialog with all those numbers in listview. I am able to do all above things but problem is when user clicks on particular telephone numebr of dialog box call application is not launching. I used below code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose Number")
           .setItems(phones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int phNo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phones[phNo]));
            startActivity(launchIntent);

        }

     }); 

     AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();            
     alertDialog.show();
```

The above code is inside textview. When user pressed on Textview dialog box is appearing with numbers in a listview. When I selected any numbers and clicked it is giving me below warning and not able to call application.

```
attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

How can I resolve my issue? Thanks in advance, regards!

Comment: What do you mean by "The above code is inside textview."? Do you have a custom TextView class?

Comment: @Gonzalo : I want to make a call so I am using launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

Comment: @Gonzalo The OP is trying to open the dialer, not another Activity in their app.

Comment: But do you want to start a new `activity`? @MikeM. I understod the dialer is opening but when clicks nothing happens

Comment: @MikeM. :  Assume that I have activity which has textview, that textview has multiple numbers. when user clicked on textview a dialog box should appear and listview with numbers

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but "inside textview" implies the code is in a TextView class. Do you mean it's in the TextView's `OnClickListener`?

Comment: @Gonzalo I think I see what you mean. I read it as saying that the dialer doesn't even open.

Comment: Yes it is not opening and giving above warning

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Choose Number")
       .setItems(phones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int phNo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phones[phNo]));
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }

 }); 

 AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();            
 alertDialog.show();
```

Add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `startActivity(launchIntent`) after  `alertDialog.show();` so because of that I was getting that warning.